# What is the difference between Preference and Secure Preference file in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, chromium

```
%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default
```

This location stores two file Preferences and Secure Preferences. What is the difference between the two and what gets modified in case of any modification in Google Chrome?

Comment: They are both JSON-formatted text files, you can easily check it yourself: copy both, change something in Chrome and see what changed using diff or other comparison tools.

Comment: Actually I am having an issue, I am installing a chrome extension which gets entry in either of them, so wanted to know in which cases do either of the files gets modified. Or is it random.

Answer (score 4):

Google Chrome has a "secure preferences" feature, that matches up the saved profile to a "good copy" - and if the two do not match Chrome will [reset the settings](https://codereview.chromium.org/271673006) when the browser is restarted. Ultimately, it's an anti-malware feature.

Some experience issues with this feature because is it prevents some admin scenarios. The problem is the secured profile is bound to a machine specific ID, as disclosed in the linked SO answer below and mentioned here in a [Chromium ticket](http://codereview.chromium.org/2634403002).

As far as I know, this feature is not documented anywhere. I think it was discovered by someone who found it in the source code, some info [How to migrate Google Chrome profile (extensions, cookies, etc.) to another Windows installation?](https://superuser.com/questions/1020479/how-to-migrate-google-chrome-profile-extensions-cookies-etc-to-another-wind/1265894#1265894)

Guessing from the [Chromium source, this feature exists on all platforms](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/browser/prefs/profile_pref_store_manager.cc?l=105) except Android/ChromeOS.

Comment: I uploaded the Preferences file for someone, am I in danger?

Comment: @Shayan I cannot speak into this. You may want to ask here: https://security.stackexchange.com/