# Chrome uses Preferences and Secure Preferences to manage extensions, what's the difference?

Tags: google-chrome, security, google-chrome-extensions, chromium

I found this post: [What is the difference between Preference and Secure Preference file in Google Chrome?](https://superuser.com/questions/1173339/what-is-the-difference-between-preference-and-secure-preference-file-in-google-c)

But I want to know further: When does Chrome decides to use `Secure Preferences` and when to use `Preferences` file for maintaining extensions?

**Case 1:**
Because I found that in my computer the newly installed extension's manifest.json file's whole content is copied to `Preferences` file. Which means Chrome uses `Preferences` file to maintain my extensions. In this case, my `Secure Preferences` file has only one line as below:

```
{"protection":{"super_mac":"abc123xxxxxxx"}}
```

In this case I can change my extension's configuration e.g. `update_url` (in the `Preferences` file) sucessfully.

**Case 2:** While in my colleague's computer the installed extension's manifest.json file's content is not copied to `Perefences` file, but it is copied to `Secure Preferences` file. Which means Chrome uses `Secure Preferences` file to maintain his extensions.
In this case I cannot change my extension's any configuration, otherwise will cause the browser to reset settings.

Why? What is the factor for Chrome to decide to use `Preferences` file or `Secure Preferences` file for maintaining the extensions?

**More：**
I found that all the Chrome browsers which are in our company domain use `Preferences`. And all the Chrome browsers which are not in our company domain use `Secure Preferences`. Both cases have nothing to do with whether the browser users login or not. But why?

Comment: Secure Preferences is not always enabled. Chrome Sync is known to enable it. Are you perhaps not using Chrome Sync, but your colleague does?

Comment: @harrymc Thank you for your reply! I update my main post, for the last part, please check it.

Comment: You haven't answered about Chrome Sync.

Comment: @harrymc Thanks for your reply! I install Chrome out of my company domain and without user login, hence no Chrome sync enabled. And it uses Secure Preferences file to manage the extensions. Which proves that not chrome sync enables Secure Preferences.